# Windows 10 clean install using Windows 7 retail key

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, 64-bit, uefi, windows-installation

I'm thinking about migrating from Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit to Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

I believe I have 2 options available to me.

> - Do a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit with retail key, then do an upgrade to Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.
> - Do a Windows 10 Pro 64 bit install using the above retail key.

Between the two options above: which process would be the better option of the two or does it not make any difference?

Before a decision is made to give an answer to the question above take into consideration the following:

I plan to wipe my hard drive completely meaning that I do not intend to just delete the partition or format the drive. I plan on using a boot-able disk image partition program to erase the drive fully (write all 0s). Then I want to install Windows 10. I plan on shifting from the standard bios of Windows NTSC to EUFI type bios and partition types if possible.

Once my hard drive is wiped clean and I begin to install Windows 10 I want to know which of the above approaches is better for a good solid clean build of Windows 10. Install Windows 7 first then upgrade? Or Install Windows 10 directly using the Windows 7 retail key? Or what is the correct procedure before I decide to begin the process of wiping my drive?

If you need more information about my current hardware do not hesitate to ask and I will provide it if needed.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not so sure about that; I think there are ways to upgrade still. I've actually done the upgrade via Oracle's VM VirtualBox using the Install Windows 7, then upgrading to Windows 10 process and it did work through the VM and I can boot up Windows 10 through the VM.

Comment: @Ramhound I had downloaded the tool from MS to create the discs long before the upgrade promotion expired; I just never did the upgrade...

Comment: If you did not perform the upgrade and then activate Windows 10, on the machine in question, then you are not eligible to use your Windows 7 license key to activate Windows 10 today.  Downloading the tool didn't achieve what is required to satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install the free Windows 7/8 -> 10 upgrade on a new empty drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/946348/can-i-install-the-free-windows-7-8-10-upgrade-on-a-new-empty-drive)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade from Windows 7 Home to Windows 10 Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/1151555/upgrade-from-windows-7-home-to-windows-10-pro/1151591#1151591)

Answer (score 3):

> Between the two options above: which process would be the better
>   option of the two or does it not make any difference?

Neither option can be used to upgrade to Windows 10 unless you previously installed Windows 10 on the machine.  The original free upgrade offer expired back in July 2016 and was extended to users who were using assistance programs until December 2017.

You will need to purchase a Windows 10 license key in order to accomplish what you want.

> I want to know which of the above approaches is better for a good
>   solid clean build of Windows 10, install Windows 7 first then upgrade?

If you had previously activated Windows 10 on the machine, then either approach would have worked exactly the same, but neither approach is a viable option at this current time.

> Install Windows 7 first then upgrade? Or Install Windows 10 directly
>   using the Windows 7 retail key? Or what is the correct procedure
>   before I decide to begin the process of wiping my drive?

There isn't an incorrect procedure.   If you use the first method, you will have to change the product key, in order to activate Windows 10.  The second method is the simplest provided you already have a Windows 10 license.  The resulting outcome of either method will be exactly the same.

Comment: Let's rephrase it: I'm not interested in the idea of the "free upgrade promotion period". I just want to know which method is the better of the two for a clean install of windows 10, regardless of the promotional period.

Comment: You can always try to upgrade. In the worst case, you end up with an unlicenced version of Windows 10, where you can always buy the license and activate at that point. The benefit of upgrading is that you keep your files and settings in tact.

Comment: @LPChip - The author specifically wants to perform a clean install.  So I doubt they are concerned with keeping their personal files.

Comment: What @Ramhound is saying is that if you have already upgraded in the past during the promotion period **and activated that copy**, and then reverted to Windows 7, you can do a clean install of Windows 10 **on the same PC** without a product key.  If you haven't, you need to buy a Windows 10 Product Key before a clean install as no upgrade is available any more.

Comment: @FrancisCugler you do understand that a clean install means leaving behind no fragments or files of the old OS?, so only one of your methods is a "clean" install.

Comment: @Moab Incorrect.  You can do a clean install of Windows 10 from within Windows 7.  You simply choose not to keep anything.  I have submitted dozens of answers to that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your comment indicates that you aren't interested in any licensing issues, but purely about the effects of upgrading vs new install here's my answer.

When you upgrade, you keep your files in tact, but you refresh the windows 10 subsystem. Given that Windows 10 is a new OS, it will be like a fresh install, then add all your programs to it.

If you use every single program you have currently installed, and a fresh install will have all these programs installed afterwards, upgrading is definitely the way to go.

If you have many programs installed that you don't use anymore, you can consider to uninstall those before upgrading, or do a completely new, fresh install.

Device drivers will in most cases not be moved over to the new installation, but installed fresh, unless the drivers come with specific software. In some cases, the software is copied, in other cases, its completely gone and needs to be installed. In either case, drivers should not be the reason to choose between upgrading or doing a clean install.